# RAFT на базе Redis

Tags: linux, веб-программирование, администрирование, redis, devops

Есть сервис, для которого необходимо сделать резервирование: запустить 3 копии на разных серверах, но работать должен только один. Очевидно, необходимо решить проблему с выбором лидера. Я слышал для таких задач обычно используют etcd3 - strong consistency key-value хранилище, но в проекте уже используется redis. Чтобы не разворачивать дополнительные сервисы, я хочу реализовать выбор лидера на базе redLock, по идеи это должно избавить от проблемы с 2 лидерами. Есть ли какие-то подводные камни в таком решении?

Comment: Теперь вам необходимо сделать 3 резервирование для Redis.